# Two channel entries loops on one page, both with pagination

Tags: ajax, jquery, pagination

I am having some issues with pagination.

I have two channel entries loops on one template, both of which have pagination enabled.

One of the loops works fine but the second one, I guess is conflicting.

For example.. the second loop is duplicating the pagination segments in the url

domain.com/P1/P2 etc..

(I am also using [this from Aaron Bushnell](https://github.com/reusserdesign/ExpressionEngine-Ajax-Pagination))

Is it even possible to work them independently on one template? Thanks!!

Comment: Just to be clear, when a pagination link is clicked/pagination segment is in the URL, do  you want **both** `channel:entries` tags to be affected in the same way? (ie that domain.com/P10 should offset both entries by 10), or to have independent pagination for each?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If yes, please mark the answer correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping each channel entries and each pagination in a conditional. If the pagination layout is identical for each channel entry section then you can throw it in a snippet. It might look something like this:

```
{if segment_2 == "pancakes"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="pancakes"}
    {title}
    {sn-pagination}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{if:elseif segment_2 == "waffles"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="waffles"}
    {title}
    {sn-pagination}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}
```

Comment: Hi Stuart, thanks for your help. It's a single page website so there are no segments to check against. I was using the jQuery to paginate without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 3):

I would do the same as Stuart McCoy, but performance wise it's better to use [switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) instead of the native advanced conditionals.

```
{exp:switchee variable = "{segment_2}" parse="inward"}

{case value="pancakes"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="pancakes" dynamic="off"}
      {title}
      {sn-pagination}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/case}

{case value="waffles" default="Yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="waffles" dynamic="off"}
      {title}
      {sn-pagination}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

don't forget to add the dynamic="off" param!

Comment: Yeah, switchee would definitely be better. I was writing on my iPad on the train to work and I didn't want to over complicate the general solution which would be to split the two into separate conditionals and see if pagination still breaks.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what Marc is looking for. I think he is looking for a way to have two entry loops with coexistent paginations on one page. Managing multiple pagination URL segments is the difficulty here.